# Which way to subdivide a hex grid?

Tags: grid, hexagonal-grid

Here are, it seems, two ways to draw a smaller grid of tiles from an initial hexagon:

[image: Hexagon subdivided]

On the left, we halve the side length \$s\$ and create most of the new tiles centered at the midpoint of sides. The area of the new regular shapes is one quarter because the parent sees one and six halves children. On the right, we use the vertices as centers for the new hexagons; the side length goes to \$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}s\$ and the area a 1:3 ratio because there will be one and six thirds children reporting to the first hexagon.

I am hoping we think through the advantages of these systems. The first may be of more convenience and reduced overhead, which could be outweighed by artistic value. But I suspect there are other criteria for my purposes and it's also a general question. (For now feeling a little bewildered by geometry.)

My project is a game map (in this iteration, a globe; both subdivision methods generalize to a starting icosahedron I think) which should have nice "zooming" properties. I want to use larger tiles to summarize features under them which can be generated in more detail at will.

Comment: Seems like the question should be structured other way round. Firstly clarify your goal, what are you trying to achieve? What goals and criteria are there. Then solutions you have identified, then their properties and details.

Comment: Does the second one really create regular hexagons all with the same size? Doesn't look like it...

Comment: @Kromster That's good enough advice but I thought this question would be welcome.

Comment: It is welcome, I'm just adding my 2c to help to improve it

Comment: There are three that I know of, starting from the sides, the vertices, or the centers. See the K=3, K=4, K=7 diagrams on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_place_theory#Predictions